# Checkbox giving no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I cannot figure out what's going on with this one. Im using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in my model and whenever ids are in the param, array, this issue happens on `create`:

> no implicit conversion of String into Integer

**Foo model:**

```
has_many :foo_perks, dependent: :destroy
has_many :perks, through: :foo_perks
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo_perks, :another_one, allow_destroy: true
```

**Foo Controller**

```
# create
Foo.create(foo_params) # Issue here

# private
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(foo_perks_attributes: [ perk_id: [] ]) # omitted title and other
end
```

Pretty standard stuffs. The view:

```
[..] # form_for(..)
<%= f.fields_for :foo_perks_attributes do |fp| %>
  <% @perks.each do |perk| %>
    <%= fp.check_box(:perk_id, { multiple: true }, perk.id, nil) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %> # end of form_for
```

An example of of the submitted params:

```
"foo"=>{"title"=>"", "foo_perks_attributes"=>{"perk_id"=>["4"]}}
```

When I manually create a `foo_perks` in the console, I see no problem, no errors. Am I doing something wrong with the permit?

`Foo` creates successfully when no ids are passed.

Comment: `f.fields_for :foo_perks` without the `_attributes` https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: hi! Ive tried that but nothing displays when i remove `_attributes`

Comment: How about `f.fields_for @perks`

Comment: Nope. When I do `<%= f.fields_for :foo_perks, @foo.foo_perks.build do |fp| %>` my checkbox's name attr looks like `foo[foo_perks_attributes][0][perk_id][]` Where that '[0]' comes from?

Comment: That's how it should be, it's an array of `foo_perks_attributes`

Comment: <%= f.fields_for :foo_perks, @perks do |fp| %>` and lose your inner loop, it's not necessary

Comment: Ok but the submitted param now looks like: `"foo_perks_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"perk_id"=>["3", "4"]}}` and the error message is `foo_perks.perk` is blank